How to make home server accessible from internet?
I am trying to make a server accessible over the internet but I am not succeeding. I have configured the sshd_config file to listen on port 22, enabled ufw to allow port 22, and configured the router to forward traffic to this port.
However, I am still getting a timeout error when trying to connect.
What else can I check to resolve this issue?
Error:

ssh:

ufw:

sshd_config:

Router configuration:

IP to connect from the internet:


please do not post pictures of text ... post the text instead

The first step is always to make sure the router itself is accessible from Internet – all your router configuration is moot if packets cannot reach that router in the first place.

You might assume that it always has a public IPv4 address, but that's not always the case – increasingly more ISPs put customers behind CGNATs, where each customer's router gets a private address that is only temporarily mapped to a public one.
In other words, just as your PCs "borrow" the router's IP address (and websites such as "What is my IP" cannot tell the difference), your router might also be "borrowing" a public IP address – and websites such as "What is my IP" would not be able to tell the difference. Your ifconfig.me is always going to see some public address, but it has absolutely no clue as to whether that address is actually dedicated to you or not.
Check the router's own "WAN status" page to find out what address it has, and compare it to what the websites show. If the router is showing a different IP address, that means you're behind CGNAT and the address from ifconfig.me is not actually yours. Some ISPs provide a dedicated public IP address as an addon that you need to order.

At the same time, some ISPs might have firewall rules blocking inbound connections to "residential customer" addresses. With CGNAT this is pretty much a given, but it is a possibility even if the router has a public address – sometimes you need to order the "static IP address" addon for the firewall restrictions to be lifted.


Assuming the router itself is accessible:

Test from outside your network – don't bother testing from inside until you know that connections from outside are working.
Port forwarding (DNAT) works in a way that requires additional trickery ("NAT hairpinning") to support "reflected" LAN-router-LAN connections, and not all routers have that feature.
Even if you know that your router has hairpin NAT supported and enabled, you should still be testing exactly what you're trying to set up – if you want the server to be accessible from outside, then test connections from outside (e.g. from a rented VPS).

Use packet capture tools as part of the test. There are tools such as Wireshark and tcpdump that let you literally see the individual packets that arrive from the network:
$ wireshark -k -i eth0 -f "port 22"   (GUI)

$ tshark -n -i eth0 -f "port 22"

$ sudo tcpdump -n -i eth0 "port 22"

If you see that a TCP SYN packet is arriving at the server, that immediately rules out half of the possible problems – i.e. it means your router and your 'port forwarding' are working fine, and the problem is likely with the server's firewall.
On the other hand, if you don't see any TCP packets on port 22, it rules out the other half (i.e. the server's firewall can't possibly be an issue because packets aren't getting to it in the first place), and means that the problem is on the ISP's or the router's side.



In your router configuration, you have "2--2" as the port numbers. This doesn't look correct. I don't know what kind of router you have, but try entering "22--22" as the port numbers, or just "22" in the first box and nothing in the second. Do this for both the internal and external port numbers. 22, as you probably know, is the normal port for SSH.
I guess you're thinking the first box is supposed to have the first digit of he port number and the second box should have the second digit? I think the two boxes for port number are supposed to let you specify a range of ports. So you could enter "22--42" in the two port number boxes and forward ports 22, 23, etc. up to 42 with a single entry.

While your internal setup looks fine, a quick way to see if an external device can see your network would be to use netcat to get the banner of your ssh server.
Using a device on another external network (ie: cellular provider), run the following command:
nc 197.249.x.x 22 where the x's are your other octets.
This should provide something like "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH". You can also try it. This will clarify if you are able to see it from the outside. That is the first step outside of your initial configuration to confirm you have true external access.
You may also need to confirm with your ISP that they allow for incoming connections to your IP address. I know in my country, depending on the service provider, you have to contact their technical support in order to gain a static IP or have them allow access to certain ports.
